# Using a variadic template template, itself with with variadic parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-specialization

Could one make a variadic template template, itself with variadic parameters?
How would one explicitly/partially specialize this template?

```
//E.g. something where the following would be valid:

template <template <typename...> typename... Containers>
    class SomeClass {};

SomeClass <int, std::vector<int>, std::tuple<int, char, float, double, short>> var;
```

I get as far as

```
template <template <typename...> typename... Tuples>
    class CVarMap : public CVarMap<Tuples>
    {};

template <template <typename...> typename Tuple, template <typename...> typename... Tuples>
    class CVarMap : public CVarMap<Tuple, Tuples...>
    {};
```

but any attempt to unpack the "inner" variadic args results in a template with multiple variadic parameters.  Yet in [the answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662632/variadic-variadic-template-templates) there are multiple variadic parameters, which is valid.

What am I missing here?

Comment: From definition, `var` is invalid, `SomeClass<std::vector, std::tuple>` would be though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible.  Do you really need template template paramters?  `template <typename... Containers> class SomeClass {};` lets you have `SomeClass <std::vector<int>, std::tuple<int, char, float, double, short>> var;`

Comment: `int, std::vector<int>, std::tuple<int, char, float, double, short>` are all types. `std::vector, std::tuple` are `template <typename...> typename`s

Comment: `class CVarMap : public CVarMap<Tuples>` would be self inheritance...

Comment: What are you wanting to do with `Containers...`  in the body of `SomeClass`?

Comment: @Jarod42 because of the `int`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I was wondering if it was possible.  As to whether one *should*...

Comment: @Caleth it was mostly an academic exercise, I see that it is not inadvisable but actually impossible.

Comment: I still don't understand what the OP is trying to do. Why would `int` be a valid template argument to `SomeClass`, if `SomeClass` is supposed to take variadic templates as arguments?

Comment: @SKNB: not only because of the `int`. As we said `<typename T>` is for types like `int`, `std::vector<int>`, `std::tuple<int, int>`; <template <typename...> class> is for template such as `std::vector` (but not `std::vector<SomeType>`) or `std::tuple`.